# C# Convert hierarchical model to other model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, hierarchical-data

I have a hierarchical data ApiGroup as shown with below properties. This get populated from Api, I want to map this model into UIGroup model with below properties.
Please suggest a efficient approach to do the same?

- ApiGroup:       List<ApiItem> Items
- ApiItem:        string Text,       List<ApiItem> SubItems

To be converted into model

- UIGroup:     List<UIItem> Items
- UIItem:      string Text,        List<UIItem> SubItems

Note:- here first retrieving hierarchical Items from Api and then map them to UI model to show on screen.

Comment: Looks the same to me. What's the problem?